# Jmeter parse and Assert Array of Json objects

Tags: json, jmeter

In Jmeter when trying to extract data from Json object everything is ok and works great but, when i have array of Json objects can't extract it.

Result is:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"test"},{"id":2,"name":"test2"}]
```

it is my project JSON Extractor and JSR233 Assertion.[image]

[image]

Inside Groovy script i'm making log.info but it doesn't  captures variable value which is described inside JSON Extraxtor.

```
String id =  vars.get("id");
 log.info ("The example answer is " + id);
   if (id == ""){
        AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("The id is  null");
            AssertionResult.setFailure(true); 
    }
```

Please note that if Json response looks like this   `{"id":1,"name":"test"}`
everything works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) Expression to look like: `$..id`. `..` is a [deep scan](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) operator so it will return all `id` attributes values.
2. Change Match No to `-1`

It will result in the following variables:

```
id_1=1
id_2=2
id_matchNr=2
```

I have no idea what exactly you need to assert, hopefully you will be able to amend your Groovy script yourself.

Also be aware that there is [JSON Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) test element available since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) so you won't need to have separate extractor and assertion elements.

Comment: i want to check if any property inside Json is null or empty.
just added  $..id and -1 now response changed.
 The example answer is null